# Не работает jquery в rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

У меня такая проблема. Есть верстка:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"> 
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyBooks</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><%= link_to "Главная",root_url%></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Каталог",catalog_url%></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Есть скрипт:

```
$(document).on('page:load',new function(){
$('li').click(new function(){
    $('li').removeClass();
       $(this).addClass('active');
   });});
```

Но он не срабатывает поскольку возникает такая ошибка:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

В чем может быть причина? Гем я установил, в application.js подключил. На странице application.html.erb подключение тоже есть.
Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '5.1.5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'faker'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sdoc', group: :doc
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'


# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  gem 'mini_backtrace'
  gem 'guard-minitest'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
end

group :development do
  gem 'letter_opener'
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
  gem 'fog-aws'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Ошибка означает, что подключили "плохо". Внимательно проверьте подключение. Можно в консоли браузера проверить доступность `jQuery` и `$`

Comment: Еще вариант, что используется [turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#installing-javascript-behavior)

Comment: Добавьте ваш application.js и Gemfile. Если в проекте есть турболинки, то будет важен порядок require в application.js

Comment: @Василиса добавил необходимые файлы.